# Generic Web Service client in java

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have list of WSDL urls in a text file. I have to invoke all of these wsdl in my java program. Each wsdl has only one opertaion. I tried to create webservice client in netbeans but it is for only one wsdl url. I want to have generic client. Kindly suggest some  API(jar) and easy tutorial for doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps [this project](http://www.computing.dcu.ie/~mwang/DI/di.html) would be suitable. I have never used it but it seems to have instructions and therefore you could call it in a loop, giving your WSDLs as an argument.

Hope I helped!

Comment: I am getting exception when I call this Sorry for late reply, I was stuck in other projects. When I call a webservice, I get this exception :
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: javax.jbi.messaging.MessagingException: HTTPBC-E00798: Message normalization failed

Comment: This link is dead.